# Meaning of `>|` in bash?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

On the [Github help page for setting up SSH keys](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/#platform-windows), there is a section with some code for Windows users to copy-paste into their `.bashrc` to auto-start the `ssh-agent`.

Here is the code they provide:

```
env=~/.ssh/agent.env

agent_load_env () { test -f "$env" && . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_start () {
    (umask 077; ssh-agent >| "$env")
    . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_load_env

# agent_run_state: 0=agent running w/ key; 1=agent w/o key; 2= agent not running
agent_run_state=$(ssh-add -l >| /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)

if [ ! "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || [ $agent_run_state = 2 ]; then
    agent_start
    ssh-add
elif [ "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && [ $agent_run_state = 1 ]; then
    ssh-add
fi

unset env
```

What is the meaning of the `>|` symbol? How does it differ from regular io-redirection such as `>` or `|`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the output directory. But I don't use bash.

Comment: You find your answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html):

> The `noclobber` option is available to avoid overwriting existing files with output redirection (see The Set Builtin). The ‘>|’ redirection operator may be used to override noclobber.

If you do:

```
set -o noclobber
echo > file
```

Then if the file `file` existed prior to execution, the second command will fail. You can overwrite the behavior with `>|`

```
set -o noclobber
echo >| file
```

Even with `noclobber` option set, the `file` if it existed will also be overwritten. I rarely see `>|` and `noclobber` option. Usually people `[ -f file ]` check the file for existence.

Comment: This is correct, but whoever wrote the OP's script seems to have gone a bit overboard with it; at least on my system, the `noclobber` option has no problem with a plain `> /dev/null`.

Answer (score 2):

`>|` is almost the same as `>`, except that it will overwrite existing regular file.

You see the difference only if you have:

```
set -o noclobber
```

Otherwise both `>|` and `>` will overwrite existing regular file.

Answer (score 1):

Is an output operator, | allows for destruction of the file if exists.

Source: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45201/bash-what-does-do